# Ожидание ответа пользователя в боте Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Я пытаюсь сделать бота, который проводит пользователю тест. Чтобы не делать множество состояний, я пытаюсь давать вопросы в цикле, однако бот присылает все вопросы разом. Как сделать, чтобы бот ждал ответа пользователя на каждый ответ, не прикручивая состояние к каждому ответу. Надеюсь такой способ есть...

```
class dialog(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    victorina = State()

# тут стартует викторина
@dp.message_handler(state=dialog.name, content_types=['text'])
async def take_name_and_start_questions(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await dialog.victorina.set()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['answers'] = []
    await state.update_data(name=msg.text)
    for questions in replies.q:
        kb = create_kb(len(questions['a']))
        text = questions['q'] + "\n"
        i = 1
        for ans in questions['a']:
            text += f'{i}) {ans} \n'
            i += 1
        await msg.answer(text, reply_markup=kb)

# тут должны обрабатываться ответы
@dp.message_handler(state=dialog.victorina, content_types=['text'])
async def save_answer(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['answers'].add(int(msg.text))

# создание клавиатуры с ответами 1-2-3 в зависимости от их числа
def create_kb(cnt: int):
    kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    for but in range(1, cnt):
        b = KeyboardButton(but)
        kb.add(b)
    return kb
```

Comment: Никак. Для этого и создана машина состояния.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь в стейт запихнуть счетчик вопросов. То есть, проверяете в data стейта некую переменную в которую вы записываете и считываете номер вопроса.
Ну и так как кода вы дали кот наплакал, я сделал его слегка по другому

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardRemove

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

questions = {
    "вопрос 1": [
        "ответ 1",
        "ответ 2",
        "ответ 3",
    ],
    "вопрос 2": [
        "ответ 1",
        "ответ 2",
        "ответ 3",
    ],
    "вопрос 3": [
        "ответ 1",
        "ответ 2",
        "ответ 3",
    ]
}


class Dialog(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    victorina = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    await Dialog.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Dialog.name)
async def take_name_and_start_questions(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['answers'] = []
        data['cur_question'] = 1
        data['name'] = msg.text

        for i, question in enumerate(questions):
            # тут выводим только первый вопрос
            if i != 0:
                break
            answers = questions[question]
            kb = create_kb(len(answers))
            text = question + "\n"
            for j, answer in enumerate(answers):
                text += f'{j + 1}) {answer} \n'

        await msg.answer(text, reply_markup=kb)

    await Dialog.victorina.set()


# тут должны обрабатываться ответы
@dp.message_handler(state=Dialog.victorina)
async def save_answer(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # добавляем ответ в массив
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['answers'].append(int(msg.text))

        # ну и выводим некст вопрос
        for i, question in enumerate(questions):
            # выводит только след вопрос
            if i == data['cur_question']:
                kb = create_kb(len(questions[question]))
                text = question + "\n"
                for j, answer in enumerate(questions[question]):
                    text += f'{i}) {answer} \n'
                # ну и чтобы зря не работал for брейкаем его
                break
        # делаем сразу некст вопрос
        data['cur_question'] += 1
    # ну и если вопросы кончились то никакого text ни kb не будет делаем проверку
    if text:
        await msg.answer(text, reply_markup=kb)
    else:
        # собственно если нету то удалаем клавиатуру и пишем что-то
        await msg.answer("конец викторины", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        # а также в зависимости как вы работаете с стейтом делате или 
        await state.finish()
        # или удаляете переменные в стейт ручками по типу
        del data['answers']  
        # и тд... Ну и само собой не забудьте забрать нужные вам данные до их удаление. Тобишь выше но в блоке елс   


# создание клавиатуры с ответами 1-2-3 в зависимости от их числа
def create_kb(count: int):
    kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    for num in range(1, count + 1):
        button = KeyboardButton(text=f"{num}")
        kb.add(button)
    return kb


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

А вообще не понимаю почему вы решили использовать клавиатурные кнопки, а не инлайн, которые были бы удобнее и не нужно было бы загромождать свой бот месседж_хендлерами.

А вот и пример работы кода
[image: пример]

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то что я искал.
Не использовал инлайн, так как не до конца с ним разобрался

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй импортировать time. И с помощью метода time.sleep() задать время через которое будет отсылаться каждый вопрос.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]